# Building a simle query page using perl and oracle

Tags: perl, cgi

I need to create a webpage using perl where in a textarea input the query will be typed and upon clicking the execute button it should execute the query and display the results in a tabularized format with columns names as heading dynamically.

[image]

So the help I am looking for is how to create the headings of columns and tables for data dynamically depending on the query, particularly how to get the column names printed dynamically as query will only fetch the data not column names for heading!

Many thanks for you help.

**Update**

There are 2 issues with Erik's code, no. one being that its not tabling meaning not bordering the results properly as you can see in the picture below, the columns should be separated by border the way its shown in 2nd picture below:

[image]

Number two, it does not print the columns in order as you can see in the picture above, the SHIPPERID column should be printed first.

The way I want it, is as under :

[image]

Here is the revised code, I will appreciate if someone help me do that as per the 2nd picture.

```
my $i = 0;
my $tableHeader ;
my @tableRows ;
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
       $tableHeader = $q->thead( $q->Tr( $q->th( map { $_ } sort keys %{$row},) ) ) if $i == 0;
      push(  @tableRows, [ $q->td( map { $row->{$_} } sort keys %{$row},) ] );
      $i++;

}
print $q->table( { -class => 'pure-table-striped', -border => 2, -bordercolor => '#989898' },
                   $tableHeader,
                   $q->Tr( [ map { join "", @$_ } @tableRows ] )
                 );
```

Many many thanks for your help !!

Comment: you completely rewrote your question. This is not good as people looking at it now will not be able to see easily what the original question was that people answered. While you can add things to react to answers, you should leave the original question in place in order not to cause this type of confusion

Comment: Edited to put back the original question. Please don't remove questions like that. It makes it harder to understand the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying Erik's code and fixing it so you always get the columns displayed in the expected order.:

```
my $dbquery = 'select * from Staff';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($dbquery);
$sth->execute();

my $table_header = $cgi->thead( $cgi->Tr( $cgi->th ( $sth->{NAME} ) ) );
my @table_rows   = map { $cgi->Tr ( $cgi->td( $_ ) ) } @{ $sth->fetchall_arrayref };

print $cgi->table(
  { -id => 'mytable' }, 
  $table_header,
  @table_rows,               
);
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Dave, your assistance is really appreciated !!

Comment: one quick question, how to get the total number of rows returned from within the routines we have ?

Comment: Yes it is. It's obviously the length of the `@table_rows` array. Why don't you see if you can use that to get the information you want.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the indicator
my $cnt = @table_rows;

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're passing your query direct to DBI, it is possible to get the column names but it is a little obscure:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute;
my @columns = @{$sth->{NAME}};
```

You can find out more in the [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#NAME1)

**EDIT**: unlike [@Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2967091/erik)'s answer above, this will give you the columns in the order you specify them in the query.

Answer (score 0):

As for semicolon try :

```
my $string = "SELECT * FROM staff;";
   $string  =~ s/\;//g;
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I will assume that you already have all of the DB connection (below assumed to be `$dbh`) etc set up and ready given that you didn't provide any information on that nor on anything that you maybe already tried. Below is a code snippet that should do what you want. For the second part of your question, if you get e.g. a hash ref for a given row, you can get the names of the columns (`map { $_ } sort keys %{$row}` creates an array from them)

```
my $dbquery = "select * from Staff";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($dbquery);
$sth->execute();
my $i = 0;
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
      $tableHeader = $cgi->thead( $cgi->Tr( 'Shipper ID', $cgi->th( [ map { $_ } grep !/Shipper ID/, sort keys %{$row} ], ) ) ) if $i == 0;
      push( @tableRows, [ $cgi->td( [ $row->{'Shipper ID'}, map { $row->{$_} } grep !/Shipper ID/, sort keys %{$row} ] ,) ] );
      $i++;

}

print $cgi->table( { -id => 'mytable' }, 
                   $tableHeader,
                   $cgi->Tr( [ map { join "", @$_ } @tableRows ] )
                 );
```

EDIT: in the first version there was a `[]` missing around the two `map` expressions. This takes care of the strange arrangement.
EDIT2: ok, so I added a hack to single out a column. Note that in this case you need to really know the name of the column, otherwise neither the `grep` nor the retrieval from the `$row` record will work.

This will execute the query and then will generate a header row from the keys of the first row and normal table rows from everything that follows and then put everything together in a table.

Note that this code is not necessarily the prettiest and/or the most efficient.

Obviously you should make sure that people don't do anything nasty with code injection when they are able to freely type queries.

Does this help?

Comment: Wow!! Excellent !! You are a pro buddy !!

Comment: One small issue remains, how do I take out the semicolun off the query entered on the first screen as shown in the picture because that results in error = thanks

Comment: @TonyaLepski I fixed the problem of the strange column arrangement, I'll see for a way to single out the column that you want as first

Comment: @TonyaLepski added another hack to single out a column

Comment: @Erik: If you get the columns as an array rather than a hash, then you'll be guaranteed to get them in the same order as the query. And you can use `$sth->{NAME}` to get an arrayref containing the column names.

Comment: @Erik, Thanks, sorry but I don't see any change for tabling the columns and as for the column arrangement the "SHIPPERID" should not be hardcoded because there will be different queries being executed its not the shipper table alone that is just an example - Please see Grant McLean's comment, if you can implement it that will be great - Many thanks for your help Erik !!

Comment: @TonyaLepski: Why can't you try to implement Grant's solution yourself? That's the best way to learn.

Comment: Thanks Erik for fixing the border issue - only the column arrangement issue remains - Rgds. Tonya

Comment: @TonyaLepski: For the column issue, see my answer or Grant's answer.

Comment: @DaveCross thanks for this neat little trick, overlooked it when reading the documentation. I am not going to change my answer, otherwise nobody will understand the long thread of comments back and forth anymore

Comment: wow, people are downvoting the answer that everybody else is referring to in this thread because....? "This answer is not useful"? Others improved upon it, fine, it does not provide the full answer in all details, granted, as I said I didn't want to pretend I came up with the full solution when some points were clearly brought up by others. But not useful? Not providing at least a fairly good idea on what needs to be done?